# my code didnt work and show me nothing error

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have a problem when trying to post a data using dropdown in codeigniter. there is no error code in dev mode in firefox.

this my controller:

```
public function cancelP(){
    if($this->session->userdata('admin')=='') {redirect('admin'); }
    $id_pengajuan= $this->input->post('id_pengajuan');
    $id_user= $this->input->post('id_users');
    $ket= $this->input->post('ket');
    $this->model_admin->cancelP($id_pengajuan);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

this my model:

```
function cancelP($id_pengajuan){
    return $this->db->query("UPDATE pengajuan set status='cancel' where   id_pengajuan='$id_pengajuan' ");
}
```

can someone help please, thank u

Comment: Did you check server log for error?

Comment: Your request may be redirected to admin when you make the request. You are also not checking, if the id is actually set in the post. You could try to log the query ($this->db->last_query()) and see if it is the right one. Also you should use $this->db->update() instead of using query yourself.

Comment: test your variables and your sql: `$updated =  $this->db->query("UPDATE pengajuan....` then `if (!$updated) die(print_r($this->db->error()));`